# Installing GIS for gis with Python is easy ...? not for me

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I really really need your help please. The fact is my problem should seem pretty simple to you.

So I have a macbook with Lion, I use python 3.3. In order to use GDAL for GIS? I downloaded the package on this website, which is recommended everywhere:
http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks

Then I install it. It is ok, but I cannot import it in my project, here is my error.
When I type `import osgeo`, I have the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import osgeo
ImportError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

I know my path is not good, wherecan I change it ?
Any ideas?

Comment: The linked website says "Python modules included have both Python 2.6 (Snow) and 2.7 (Lion & Mt Lion) versions", so does it work with older versions of Python?

Comment: On Gdal Website
dependencies : Python 2.X (and 3.X since GDAL 1.7.0). Python 2 versions known to work range from 2.3 to 2.7.

Comment: True if you compile GDAL yourself, but you installed a pre-packed version that works for Python versions 2.6 and 2.7. So again, does it work for these versions?